# Thumbnail image from .3gp file

Tags: ffmpeg, 3gp

Does anybody know how to get thumbnail (still image) from 3gb video file? First frame or something like that. I'm using .net, but solution can be in any language (managed or native), or third-party product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is using ffmpeg on Linux and called from PHP, but if you can use ffmpeg then that dosen't matter:

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/your/video.3gp -an -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:01 -y -s 400x300 path/to/your/image%d.jpg
```

Note the "%d"; you are only generating one frame but ffmpeg still needs this so it knows where to put the number when it is generating the images. So you will end up with a name like "image1.jpg"

Comment: That was quick! Thanx Jan. And stackoverflow rules :)

Comment: How to take about 4 thumbnails from the entire video?